# Python: Using join() and map() for a list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, join, tuples

I am trying to merge a list of tuples, say:
    `test = [('X','X'),('O','O'),('X','X')]`
into
    `test_merge = ['XX','OO','XX']`

And I read from another person that he/she uses:

> map(''.join, test)
>   and got:
>   ['XX', 'OO', 'XX']

So I thought about trying a different way:

> ''.join(map(str, test))
>   and got:
>   "('X', 'X')('O', 'O')('X', 'X')"

I understand that `''.join` cannot be used without the `test` being a list of string. But, with the same map() and join(), how come `map(''join, test)` succeeds in merging the values in a tuple? Many thanks!

Comment: When I run map(''.join, test), I get ['XX', 'OO', 'XX']. Do you have a typo in your test string?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Indeed there is a typo. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` sends each element in the iterable to the given function. Watch what happens when we call each of the functions you tried:

```
>>> ''.join(('X', 'X'))
'XX'
>>> str(('X', 'X'))
"('X', 'X')"
```

As you can see, `''.join` joins all of the passed iterable's arguments with a delimiter of an empty string, producing the results you want. `str`, however, produces the string representation of the passed object, as demonstrated above, which is a `tuple` in this case. It will not attempt to do any other kind of processing on the passed object.

Comment: Hi TigerhawkT3, many thanks for the clarification. Went through a process myself as well last night and everything makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
[''.join(x) for x in test]
```

Comment: I think OP is asking why they got the results they got, rather than requesting alternative ways to accomplish a task they can already do (with no explanation, either).